# Unable to run WebDriverAgent on the real device using Appium Desktop

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am unable to run WebDriverAgent on a real device using Appium Desktop. I have attached gist for the error log.

I have tried some solution from github/appium but it did not solve my issue.

**server log**

https://gist.github.com/guowang94/ec923da6a3b77aca06a902c450200238

**appium.app error message**

https://gist.github.com/guowang94/ef2c5bb5bcc617baa2af19418e9a8b8e

I expect the WebDriverAgent to be running in the real device so that I can proceed to my next task but I am unable to install and run WebDriverAgent on the real device

Comment: Try to use appium 1.12.1 version. I am also unable to run my script on 1.13.0 version. After switching to 1.12.1 it works fine. Also follow [this guide](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md) to run appium test on real device.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs have both the problem:

> An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'UI Testing Bundle'. (in target 'WebDriverAgentRunner')

which indicates incorrect XCode configuration with regards to signing the WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app

and the solution:

> Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 .... Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

If the official guide is not clear you can follow steps from the [Configuring Appium Environment for iOS Real Device](https://medium.com/@marjorieivy/configuring-appium-environment-for-ios-real-device-310c7bc863e4) article.

---

You can also consider [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/appium/when-appium-for-ios-is-not-getting-it-done-enter-appium-studio/) which makes the process of setting up Appium testing on real iOS devices much easier.